# How to create folder in my android file manager via kivy android application

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to develop android application by using kivy. For testing I need to select an image from my internal storage, convert it into gray scale image and it needs to be stored in a particular folder.

I was wondering how to achieve this, every option is welcome.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you are trying to show an image from a particular folder. You can achieve this by adding a image to your .kv file:

```
Image:
     source: '/myfolder/mylogo.png'
```

Or if you are getting the path from you python file. You can use get the path by calling the function in your kv file which you can use this:

```
<MyScreen>:
     on_pre_enter: get_image()
     image:
         size: self.width self.height
```